# Unable to display data in the second view controller using segue [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I need to pass data from one view controller to another view controller. I used segue (detail) and define a model class named as "Photo".

TableViewController looks like the following:

```
var photos = [Photo]()  //strongly typed swift array

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var newPhoto = Photo(name:"cat ", fileName:"cat", notes:"cat_file")
        photos.append(newPhoto)

        var newPhoto2 = Photo(name:"r2 ", fileName:"r2", notes:"r2")
        photos.append(newPhoto2)


    }
```

And the other view controller (DetailViewController) looks like the following:

```
import UIKit

class PhotoDiplayViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentPhoto: Photo?


    @IBOutlet weak var currentImage: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var currentLabel: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var image = UIImage(named: currentPhoto!.fileName)
        self.currentImage.image = image

        self.currentLabel.text = currentPhoto?.name
        println(currentPhoto!.name  + currentPhoto!.fileName + currentPhoto!.notes)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

When I am running the program, the table view is loading fine and if i click on any cell it is going to the detail view controller. but noting is there in the detail view controller. And I used println() to check and the output is coming in the debugger like the following:

```
cat cat cat_file
```

To pass data, I used the following segue code block:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoDiplayViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
            let selectedPhoto  = photos[indexPath.row]
            secondScene.currentPhoto = selectedPhoto
        }

    }
```

But still no luck! Tried to figure out where I am missing? Can anybody tell me where I am lagging?

**UPDATE:** complete detail view controller class code

UPDATE: Full detail of My table view code

```
import UIKit

class PhotoTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var photos = [Photo]()  //strongly typed swift array

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var newPhoto = Photo(name:"cat ", fileName:"cat", notes:"cat_file")
        photos.append(newPhoto)

        var newPhoto2 = Photo(name:"r2 ", fileName:"face.jpg", notes:"r2")
        photos.append(newPhoto2)


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return photos.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("photoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        var currentPhoto = photos[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = currentPhoto.name

        return cell
    }


    /*
    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }    
    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
    */

    /*
    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
    */


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        var secondScene = segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoDiplayViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow(){
            let selectedPhoto  = photos[indexPath.row]
            secondScene.currentPhoto = selectedPhoto
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Double check the image name, is it matching?

Comment: Can to share your entire DetailViewController class? Does it look like this? class PhotoDisplayViewController: UIViewController {...?

Comment: In your PhotoDisplayViewController class, I suggest adding something like this to didViewLoad() to ensure the object is being passed.     if let myPhoto = currentPhoto {....

Comment: @Esric Qian : the image name is matched properly. I tried to check that and the console output is there. Moreover, the text field is not also displaying there :(

Comment: The code looks fine. Have you checked `image` in `PhotoDiplayViewController` is non-nil and has been loaded correctly? Have you linked the `currentImage` and `currentLabel` to their Storyboard objects?

Comment: @Robotic: Yes, I checked that those are not nil. In my code, I used the line `println(currentPhoto!.name  + currentPhoto!.fileName + currentPhoto!.notes) ` to check that. And I also linked those properly to their Storyboard. One thing, I am using Navigation controller, is it creating problem? but I guess not because I am getting the correct output in the console. the only problem is drawing the output to the view.

Comment: Not the `currentPhoto` information - that is obviously non-nil. I was asking about the `image` variable loaded from `UIImage(named: currentPhoto!.fileName)`

Comment: if that is nil then....how that object info will be passed to the detail view? am i right?

Comment: @ Robotic Cat: I have uploaded full code for my first view controller.

Comment: Segue is the right way to do this, and your code looks correct. I have done something similar many times. Make sure the IBOutlets in your detail view controller are wired up correctly in your storyboard. Make sure your image variable is not nil as was suggested above. This should be easy to track down.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a segue. Use this, its easier.

Follow these steps...

1: Create a Separate file called Manager.swift and place this code in it...

```
//manager.swift

    import Foundation

    struct Manager {

    static var dataToPass = String()


    }
```

2: Clean your project by pressing Shift+Command+K.

3: In the first view controller set the dataToPass to the data you want to pass...

```
Manager.dataToPass = self.dataToPass
```

4: In the second view controller retrieve the data and set the content to the dataToPass...

```
self.dataToReceive = Manager.dataToPass
```

5: Your Finished!!

Comment: I'm thinking the solution which you mentioned. You mentioned not to use Segue, but I do not know the reason. Can you please explain the reason to avoid segue.

Comment: This is like a global variable. I wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: I recommend using this way because its much easier to manage and create. Using a segue is a complicated and unnecessary step just to pass a little data.

Answer (score 0):

The code which I presented is working fully after deleting all the image view and label from the storyboard and remapping. But I am wondering what was the problem. However, I want to share one screen shot:

[image: storyboard components]

In the screen shot, you will see 3 components: 2 labels and 1 image view. One 1 label's text is dark black colored but the for the other 2 it's not alike them. All of them are properly configured.

Still I don't know why this happens? I am not sure .... is it possible to add some hidden components on the top of storyboard??? or is it a bug of Xcode????

However, if you have similar experience please share. My aim is not only solve the problem but also to understand the cause of the problem.

:)

Comment: This isn't a bug, this is the installed property ,that  is size class dependent.EX Image View is installed only on wRegular hAny.http://i.imgur.com/uqtKW28.png